# Spark : Avro RDD to csv

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, rdd

I am able to read `arvo` file into `avroRDD` and am trying to convert into `csvRDD` which contain all the values in comma separated. With the following code I am able to read specific field into `csvRDD`.

```
val csvRDD = avroRDD .map({case (u, _) => u.datum.get("empname")})
```

How can I read all the values into `csvRDD` instead of specifying field names. My result `csvRDD` should contain records as follows

```
(100,John,25,IN)
(101,Ricky,38,AUS)
(102,Chris,68,US)
```

Comment: How were you able to create the avroRDD. was it using spark SQL (sqlContext) or directly using SparkContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Spark 1.2+ with the [Spark-Avro integration library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) by Databricks, one can convert an avro rdd to a csv rdd as follows:

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val episodes = sqlContext.avroFile("episodes.avro")
val csv = episodes.map(_.mkString(","))
```

Running `csv.collect().foreach(println)` using [this sample avro file](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/master/src/test/resources/episodes.avro) prints

```
The Eleventh Hour,3 April 2010,11
The Doctor's Wife,14 May 2011,11
Horror of Fang Rock,3 September 1977,4
An Unearthly Child,23 November 1963,1
The Mysterious Planet,6 September 1986,6
Rose,26 March 2005,9
...
```